# Evaluating indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

Evaluate the following indefinite integral.

$$\int { \frac { x }{ 4+{ x }^{ 4 } }  }\,dx$$

In my homework hints, it says let $ u = x^2 $. But still i can't continue.

Comment: Why can't you continue? Can you show us how far you get before getting stuck? What happens when you perform the substitution $u = x^2$?

Comment: $ \int { \frac { x }{ 4+{ ({ x }^{ 2 }) }^{ 2 } }  } \quad dx\\ \\ \int { \frac { \sqrt { u }  }{ 4+{ u }^{ 2 } }  } \quad dx\\ \\ \int { \frac { \sqrt { u }  }{ 4+{ u }^{ 2 } }  } \quad \frac { du }{ 2x }  $ Then what ?

Comment: So far so good! I'll reply with an answer containing more suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You've substituted $u = x^2$ and found that your original integral becomes

$$
\int\frac{\sqrt u}{4+u^2} \frac{du}{2x},
$$

but you haven't completed the substitution; there's still an $x$ in your integrand. How can you rewrite the $2x$ below the $du$ as a function of $u$? Once you rewrite $2x$ in terms of $u$, you should be able to algebraically simplify further.

Hint 2: You now have it in terms of $u$. Good! Do you see any way to simplify the integral? It may help to rewrite it as

$$
\int\frac{\sqrt u}{2\sqrt{u}(4+u^2)}du.
$$

Comment: $ \int { \frac { \sqrt { u }  }{ 4+{ u }^{ 2 } }  } \quad \frac { du }{ 2\sqrt { u }  }  $ . Actually I'm a bit rusty in algebra so i still can't figure it out.

Comment: @Tennisman: See my edit.

Comment: Yeah now i got it :) Thank you Dan :)

Comment: Happy to help! `:)`

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $u=x^2$ then $x=\sqrt u$ and $du=2x\,dx$.

Comment: $ \int { \frac { x }{ 4+{ ({ x }^{ 2 }) }^{ 2 } }  } \quad dx\\ \\ \int { \frac { \sqrt { u }  }{ 4+{ u }^{ 2 } }  } \quad dx\\ \\ \int { \frac { \sqrt { u }  }{ 4+{ u }^{ 2 } }  } \quad \frac { du }{ 2x }  $ Then what ?

Comment: Yes. $\displaystyle\int\frac{x}{4+u^2}\,\frac{du}{2x}$

Answer (score 2):

**Solve:**
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\frac{x}{4+x^{4}}dx&=&\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{4+u^2}; \text{ if $u=x^{2}$}\\
&=& \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}\arctan{\frac{u}{2}})\\
&=&\frac{1}{4}\arctan{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+C}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#0000ff}{\large\int{x\,\dd x \over 4 + x^{4}}}&=
\int x\pars{{1 \over x^{2} - 2\ic} - {1 \over x^{2} + 2\ic}}\,{1 \over 4\ic}\,\dd x
=
\half\,\Im\int{x\,\dd x \over x^{2} - 2\ic}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 4}\,\Im\ln\pars{x^{2} - 2\ic}=
{1 \over 4}\,\arctan\pars{-2 \over \phantom{-}x^{2}}= \color{#0000ff}{\large -\,{1 \over 4}\,\arctan\pars{2 \over x^{2}}}
+ \mbox{"a constant"}
\\[3mm]&= \color{#0000ff}{\large {1 \over 4}\,\arctan\pars{x^{2} \over 2}}
+ \mbox{"some constant"}
\end{align}

> Let's check it:
> \begin{align}
> \totald{}{x}\bracks{-\,{1 \over 4}\,\arctan\pars{2 \over x^{2}}}
> &=
> -\,{1 \over 4}\,
> {1 \over \pars{2/x^{2}}^{2} + 1}\,\bracks{2\,\pars{-\,{2 \over x^{3}}}}
> =
> -\,{1 \over 4}\,
> {x^{4} \over 4 + x^{4}}\,\pars{-4 \over \phantom{-}x^{3}}
> \\[3mm]&={x \over 4 + x^{4}}
> \end{align}